# Change user-agent python + selenium + firefox

Tags: user-agent

I am creating a script with python + selenium + firefox. While loading firefox I am including the following addon - https://github.com/muzuiget/user_agent_overrider . It overrides user-agent with just one click.

I need to simulate that from my code. So what i need is the following:
1. I open a page with default user-agent.
2. Script should change the user-agent while Firefox is still running (using the addon from above) and visits the same page.

I did look at the source code of the addon, but I just can't trigger the right function :)

Answer (score 0):

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.firefox_profile import FirefoxProfile


ff_profile = FirefoxProfile()
ff_profile.set_preference("general.useragent.override", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/40.0.2214.85 Safari/537.36")

driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_profle = ff_profile)
driver.get('http://www.whatismybrowser.org')
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a typo in the last answer.. i did a stupid copy/paste and it took me 20 minutes to realise it -_-

```
driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_profle = ff_profile)
```

should be

```
driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_profile = ff_profile)
```